# A-frame random generator

Tags: javascript, aframe

I need to create a random enviroment in a-frame using javascript.

```
<a-entity id="tree" position="0 1 -3">
                <a-box  rotation="90 0 90" scale="1 1 3" color="#6e583f"></a-box>
                <a-box scale="2 2 2" position="0 2.3 0" color="#4bbd53"></a-box>
 </a-entity>
```

This entity needs to be created on a random x and z position but i cant find the way to randomly do it and to make many of them with a single for cycle.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please show some gratitude by clicking on the check button next to the answer. Good karma points for all involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this with a single custom component.
You make an empty entity, and attach a single word (the name of your custom component), and inside the component, you can create an array of new entities, and add components to them, for geometry, position, material, etc. Then use Math.random() to randomize whatever attributes you like (x pos, z pos etc).

Here is an [example glitch](https://glitch.com/~random-cubes).